# Why has this jQuery Scroller stopped scrolling on my site?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008-r2, scroller

The section on the right-hand side of this website has stopped scrolling all of a sudden.

http://www.nwfencingco.com/

It is ASP.NET MVC 3, hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. It was working and looking at the server update history, the following updates were installed on 30th June.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545698
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2552343
 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547666

None of these appear to be related to IIS, but as it was working then suddenly stopped the other day seems strange.

I have checked the site in:

Chrome 12.0.742.112
Firefox 5.0
IE9
Safari 5.0.5

..all have the issue, so it doesn't appear to be browser-related.

I get these two errors in the console now when I view the site in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
http://www.nwfencingco.com/:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try
    {
        $('.vertical_scroller').SetScroller({

$ is not defined
```

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this please? I'm doing some other work on the site now, so will be changing it slightly, but don't want to lose days in this issue, so hopefully someone else has seen something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How many times do you intend to include jQuery in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Seems a bit wasteful to me.

Comment: Ah sorry I'm fairly new to jQuery. Given the jQuery Scroller plugin I'm using, which one should I remove?

Comment: @Michael, that's not the jQuery scroller plugin. Those are both the jQuery library itself. The first is the source code and the second is the minified version. So remove the first and keep the second only as it is smaller size.

Comment: I just meant which one should I remove so that I don't break my other Scroller plugin that uses jQuery. I will remove the first one thanks.

Comment: @Michael, those two scripts represent jQuery under two different forms. They have the same contents. It's just that the second is compressed.